# What is "delta" in R function power.t.test() and how i can get it?

Tags: r, statistics

I need to get the minimum amount of data in each group needed for some power and significance levels. I have two samples(quantitative,continuous) of different sizes.

I find function power.t.test() in R, but i don't understand what is "delta" parameter. In documentation:

> delta: true difference in means

But what does this mean? abs(mean(sample_1) - mean(sample_2))?

Comment: The `power.t.test` function tells you how large a sample you need to get a certain level of statistical power in a t-test. For example, if I believe that there is a difference in average height between men and women of at least 5cm, and I know that the standard devation of adult height is about 6cm, then I can do `power.t.test(delta = 5, sd = 6, power = 0.8)`, which will tell me that I need to sample at least 24 men and 24 women to have an 80% probability of detecting a difference of this size (i.e. a 20% chance of falsely accepting the null hypothesis). _You_ determine the delta you want.

Comment: my teacher said that in lectures there was a formula for calculating delta, but I could not find it x_x ok, tnx, let's try difference of means in samples and will see xD

Comment: I guess this is how you might carry out a post-hoc power calculation if you have already collected the data, but [this is often a misleading measurement](https://gpsych.bmj.com/content/32/4/e100069)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `delta` is:

- For the case of a `one.sample`, `one.sided` test, delta is equal to μ−μ0, i.e. the difference between the true (population) mean μ and the lower bound of your null hypothesis.  For instance, if your goal is to detect whether the true value μ is greater than 0 (a one-sided or one-tailed test), then μ0=0 so delta=μ.  Two more examples assuming the true value of μ were 5: If your test was to see whether μ>4, then delta=1 (regardless of the value of `sd`; delta is **not** a z-score).  If your test is to see whether the true value of μ is greater than 7, then delta would be -2.
- For the case of a `two.sample`, `two.sided` test, as another example, the yes/no question that this frequentist approach is asking is whether the true difference between means of the two groups is greater than some value delta. I.e., if μ1-μ2 > delta OR μ1-μ2 < -delta.  So delta is always positive in this case, unlike the one.sample case, above.

Here's an example of how the cases above might look:

```
power.t.test(n=9, sd=3, delta=-2, alternative='one.sided', type='one.sample')
```

```
power.t.test(n=9, sd=3, delta=1.5, alternative='two.sided', type='two.sample')
```

I think the R documentation is wholly insufficient for this function.